# Real part of a sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, summation

I would like to take the real part of the following expression:

```
Sum[(a[i] + I b[i]) r^i/(r^2 + z^2)^i, {i, 0, 2 n}]
```

where all of `a`, `b`, `r` and `z` are real and get

```
Sum[a[i] r^i/(r^2 + z^2)^i, {i, 0, 2 n}]
```

However every combination of `Re`, `ComplexExpand`, `Simplify` with `Assumptions` that I've tried just gives

```
Re[Sum[(a[i] + I b[i]) r^i/(r^2 + z^2)^i, {i, 0, 2 n}]]
```

In the end I'd like to get the real/imaginary parts of more complex expressions, such as `Re[(Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] - ξ[r, z])/(Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + ξ[r, z])]`, where `ξ` is the sum above.

Comment: `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: With `expression = Sum[(a[i] + I b[i]) r^i/(r^2 + z^2)^i, {i, 0, 2 n}]`, perhaps `expression /. I -> 0` and `expression /. _ + I y_ :> y`?

Comment: @kguler while this would work for the initial sum, it wouldn't work for the more complicated expression, since that also has a complex denominator

Comment: publius10, for the more complex expression  try `\[Xi][r_, z_] := expression;
expression2 = 
  Re[(Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] - \[Xi][r, z])/(Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + \[Xi][r, z])];
Through@{# /. I -> 0 &, # /. _ + I y_ :> y &}@expression2`?

Comment: @kguler this just gives me `Re[...]/Re[...]`. I tried using my own conjugate function and doing `(Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] - \[Xi][r, z])conj[Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + \[Xi][r, z]]/((Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + \[Xi][r, z])conj[Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + \[Xi][r, z]])` but that just simplifies, and if i force-Expand it it just gives me a mess.